# Java Regex for multiline text

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a string against a regex in Java. The string is multiline and therefore contains multiple `\n` like the followings

```
String text = "abcde\n"
        + "fghij\n"
        + "klmno\n";
String regex = "\\S*";
System.out.println(text.matches(regex));
```

I only want to match whether the text contains at least a non-whitespace character. The output is false. I have also tried `\\S*(\n)*` for the regex, which also returns false.

In the real program, both the text and regex are not hard-coded. What is the right regex to check is a multiline string contains any non-whitespace character?

Comment: The problem is not to do with the multi lines, directly. It is that `matches` matches the whole string, not just a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to do with the multi lines, directly. It is that `matches` matches the whole string, not just a part of it.

If you want to check for at least one non-whitespace character, use:

```
"\\s*\\S[\\s\\S]*"
```

Which means

- Zero or more whitespace characters at the start of the string
- One non-whitespace character
- Zero or more other characters (whitespace or non-whitespace) up to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether there is at least one non white space character in the string, you can just **trim** the text and check the size without involving regex at all.

```
String text = "abcde\n"
    + "fghij\n"
    + "klmno\n";
if (!text.trim().isEmpty()){
    //your logic here
}
```

If you really want to use regex, you can use a simple regex like below.

```
String text = "abcde\n"
    + "fghij\n"
    + "klmno\n";
String regex = ".*\\S+.*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()){
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.matches()`

```
!text.matches("\\s*")
```

Check if the input text consist solely of whitespace characters (this includes newlines), invert the match result with `!`

Using `Matcher.find()`

```
Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\S");
regexp.matcher(text).find()
```

Will search for the first non-whitespace character, which is more efficient as it will stop on the first match and also uses a pre-compiled pattern.